# How to: Organize Buttons and stuff with JavaFX

Tags: java, css, user-interface, button, javafx

I thought that a could import my JavaFX code into SceneBuilder, i don't know if it's possible or what. 
What i want is to get my GUI modules(buttons, text fields etc) in the right position. I'm having a really hard time because this is my first time using javafx and the tutorial i saw was using grid pane.
I will thank a lot some help or advice on how to get things into shape and right position. Here is my code if needed:

```
            package application;

            import javafx.scene.control.Button;
            import javafx.scene.control.ChoiceBox;
            import javafx.scene.control.Label;
            import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
            import javafx.scene.image.Image;
            import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
            import javafx.application.Application;
            import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
            import javafx.event.EventHandler;
            import javafx.geometry.Insets;
            import javafx.stage.Stage;
            import javafx.scene.Scene;
            import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
            import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
            import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
            import javafx.scene.text.Font;
            import javafx.scene.text.FontWeight;


            public class Main extends Application implementsEventHandler<ActionEvent>{

                // crea los botones 
                Button historial;   
                Button jugar;
                String jugadaComp="El jugador numero once es feo";
                int posBal=0;
                int contGA=0;
                int contGR=0;

                public static void main(String[] args) {
                    launch(args);
                }

                @Override
                //nombre de la ventana principal
                public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
                    primaryStage.setTitle("Football Simulator 2016");

                    //crea los drop list
                    ChoiceBox<String> jugadasArbitro = new ChoiceBox<>();
                    jugadasArbitro.getItems().addAll("Saque de banda","Tiro de esquina","Falta","Falta(Tarjeta amarilla)", "Falta (Tarjeta roja)", "Mano","Posicion adelantada","Penal","Fuera de juego", "Gol");
                    ChoiceBox<String> jugadasOfensivas = new ChoiceBox<>();
                    jugadasOfensivas.getItems().addAll("Pase","Pase largo","Tiro a puerta");
                    ChoiceBox<String> jugadasDefensivas = new ChoiceBox<>();
                    jugadasDefensivas.getItems().addAll("Intercepcion");


                    //inicializa botones
                    Label CGA = new Label("Goles Equipo Azul");
                    Label CGR = new Label("Goles Equipo Rojo");
                    TextField golA= new TextField(String.valueOf(contGA));
                    golA.setEditable(false);
                    golA.setPrefWidth(75);
                    golA.setPrefHeight(75);
                    golA.setFont(Font.font("Verdana",FontWeight.BOLD, 40));
                    TextField golR= new TextField(String.valueOf(contGR));
                    golR.setEditable(false);
                    golR.setPrefWidth(75);
                    golR.setPrefHeight(75);
                    golR.setFont(Font.font("Verdana",FontWeight.BOLD, 40));
                    TextField tiempo = new TextField();
                    //tiempo.setPrefWidth(5);
                    TextField jugada = new TextField(jugadaComp);
                    jugada.setPrefWidth(300);
                    jugada.setEditable(false);
                    historial = new Button("Historial");
                    historial.setOnAction(e ->historialBox.display("Historial", "de lo mio mete tu historial aqui \n no bulto manito hasta salto de linea"));
                    jugar= new Button("Jugar");
                    jugar.setOnAction(e ->{ isInt(tiempo,tiempo.getText());
                    getArbitro(jugadasArbitro);
                    getOfensiva(jugadasOfensivas);
                    getDefensa(jugadasDefensivas);
                    });

                    //agrega imagenes segun posesion del balon
                    ImageView pelotaA = new ImageView(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/res/PelotaA.png"), 100, 100, true, true));
                    ImageView pelotaR = new ImageView(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/res/PelotaR.png"), 100, 100, true, true));

                    //forma del Gui y posiciona los botones
                    GridPane grid = new GridPane();
                    grid.setPadding(new Insets(10,10,10,10));
                    grid.setVgap(8);
                    grid.setHgap(10);
                    GridPane.setConstraints(CGA, 0, 0);
                    GridPane.setConstraints(golA, 0, 2);
                    GridPane.setConstraints(CGR, 37, 0);
                    GridPane.setConstraints(golR, 37, 2);       
                    GridPane.setConstraints(pelotaA, 18, 2);
                    GridPane.setConstraints(pelotaR, 18, 2);
                    GridPane.setConstraints(historial, 0, 4);
                    GridPane.setConstraints(jugar, 37, 10);
                    //GridPane.setConstraints(jugadasArbitro, 7, 4);
                    //GridPane.setConstraints(jugadasOfensivas, 3, 4);
                    //GridPane.setConstraints(jugadasDefensivas, 3, 5);
                    //GridPane.setConstraints(jugada, 3, 6);

                    grid.getChildren().addAll(golA,golR,CGA,CGR,pelotaA,pelotaR,historial,jugar);

                    //tamanio de la ventana
                    Scene scene = new Scene(grid, 700,300);
                    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
                    primaryStage.show();

                }

                //leen el valor de los drop box
                private void getDefensa(ChoiceBox<String> jugadasDefensivas) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    String opcionDefensa = jugadasDefensivas.getValue();
                    System.out.println(opcionDefensa);
                }

                private void getOfensiva(ChoiceBox<String> jugadasOfensivas) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    String opcionOfensiva = jugadasOfensivas.getValue();
                    System.out.println(opcionOfensiva);
                }

                private void getArbitro(ChoiceBox<String> jugadasArbitro) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    String opcionArbitro = jugadasArbitro.getValue();
                    System.out.println(opcionArbitro);
                }

                //valida que el tiempo solo sea INT
                private boolean isInt(TextField tiempo, String message) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    try{
                        int minutos = Integer.parseInt(tiempo.getText());
                        return true;
                    }catch (NumberFormatException e){}
                    System.out.println("Error: introduzca numeros solamente");
                    return false;

                }

                @Override
                public void handle(ActionEvent event) {


                }

            }
```

Comment: You need a proper intro into layout management first, that will teach you how to organize your UI components properly. I recommend this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/layout-tutorial/index.html

Answer (score 0):

One problem beings your new to javafx is that you do not know how to properly format a gridpane. If you would like to move your nodes freely simply use an AnchorPane. As to designing your GUI In scene builder, depending on your IDE, you can right click your XML file and click open in scene builder. If this option is not available open your file manually in scene builder and remember to save it before running your application or the changes you made will not be present. 
Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to organize an interface. If you are organizing things into a `GridPane` then your basically putting UI elements into a spreadsheet. Otherwise you could place the buttons into a `VBox`(vertical alignment of components) or `HBox`(horizontal alignment of components). You could use an `AnchorPane` to move things towards edges or a `BorderPane` to place things in relative areas(left, right, center, top or bottom). They are also `FlowLayouts` that works similar to a `GridPane` but has its own unique characteristic. `StackPane`s are used for stacking elements on top of each other. Each have their advantages and disadvantages if you want specific advice on them check the documentation or ask on the website. For your specific situation I would suggest a `VBox` personally, but it is all your choice.